# router raise error for any other route than slash

Tags: vlang

**CONTEXT**

I have this program in `src/index.v`

```golang
import vweb

struct App {
    vweb.Context
}

["/"]
pub fn (mut app App) home_index() vweb.Result {
    return app.html("home")
}

["/about"]
pub fn (mut app App) about_index() vweb.Result {
    return app.html("about")
}

fn main() {
    vweb.run<App>(80)
}
```

And I run this command to compile it

```sh
v -o dist/index src/index.v
```

And when I run this command the server is up

```sh
./dist/index
```

**PROBLEM**

When I browse http://localhost, I see the home text, but when I browse http://localhost/about, I see this error printed in my console:

```sh
./dist/index
[Vweb] Running app on http://localhost:80
V panic: array.get: index out of range (i == -1, a.len == 0)
v hash: b3890e2
C.backtrace returned less than 2 frames
```

I noted that if I remove the home route code block, no error is raised (but I do not know how to display a response when the "/" route is found for the moment).

**QUESTION**

Does anyone knows why this error occurs?

**NOTES**

My v version

```sh
v --version
V 0.2.2 b3890e2
```

My OS version

```sh
cat /etc/issue
Welcome to Alpine Linux 3.11
```

Gcc version

```sh
gcc --version
gcc (Alpine 9.3.0) 9.3.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the framwork vweb.
It's being addressed in [PR #10001](https://github.com/vlang/v/pull/10001).